# Who can explain the ready shortcut of jQuery source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am reading the source code of `jQuery`, but I feel confused when I read the init function, that is about set ready function and can be a shortcut of `$(document).ready(function);`

```
$(document)[jQuery.fn.ready ? "ready" :"load"](function(){
    alert("hello");
})
```

just help me explain why it can set the ready event and bind my function. and how `$()[]()` works? thanks.

Comment: Not sure if that check is needed. Can;t image an untampered version of jQuery with ready missing.

Comment: Where exactly did you find this code? It's surely **not** part of jQuery.

Comment: I Imitate old version jQuery 1.2.6 and write a test, the function{alert("hello")} is just an example of selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document)[jQuery.fn.ready ? "ready" :"load"]
```

resolves to  `$(document).ready` or `$(document).load`

depending on the truthy of `jQuery.fn.ready`.

Afterwards the chosen function is simply called.

---

Note that doing so makes no sense at all `$.fn.ready` is a function that's always defined - even in the oldest jQuery version available (1.0.1). So it will never fall back to using `load` instead.

Comment: thanks again, I only know this is a choice between .ready or .load, but it's so amazing that can resolves these two function only by it's string name, it even didn't have a "." just like $(document).ready() ,maybe my bases are too weak.

Comment: `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` are exactly the same thing - but the bracket syntax allows you to use any expression instead of just a static string.

Comment: yeah! got it, all is child of foo, include functions.all is object~

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, maybe in JS (and JQuery therefor) Object can be acessed like array, so

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

is same as

```
$(document)["ready"](function() {});
```

then you just choose between ready and load functions.

Comment: yeah,it looks strange,now I understand it.